# why events in React have uppercase letter in the second key word?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React, just a question on a quirk in react event. I know that JSX is a mix of html and js, below is an example:

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>
```

but in html, it is:

```
<button onclick="handleClick()">Click</button>
```

so why React forces to have the first letter of second word to be uppercase? why it can't be

```
<button onclick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>
```

Comment: Read about synthetic events: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html

Comment: Because it's JSX, not regular HTML. Same reason you must use `className` instead of `class`, since JSX isn't regular HTML and JS, it's its own special syntax.

Comment: @Jayce444 the reason for using ```className``` instead of ```class``` is due to the fact that ```class``` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript.

Comment: @SibasishMohanty   onClick is not a reserved keyword, is it?

Comment: @amjad no, it is not. Reserved words are words that have a special meaning in the context of the language. The onClick function has no special meaning to the language javascript, but only has a meaning to the browser, therefore it is not a reserved word.

Comment: @SibasishMohanty  so why react doesn't use `onclick` instead of `onClick`, which is inconsistent with html standard?

Answer (score 1):

Simply because [React implements a **browser-independent** DOM System](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html) for performance and cross-browser compatibility.

Thus, the DOM elements and its attributes including event handlers **should** be in camel case.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way the React events are named, these events are different from normal HTML events as they are capable of doing a whole range of other things. As for why they are named like this, they use the camelCase standard.

I would suggest taking a look at this page to answer any more questions you have about events in React: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html