# MUI Input doesn't allow oninput attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have an MUI Input component defined like this where the `oninput` (tried as `onInput` as well) attribute doesn't get picked by MUI

```
  <Input
    variant="standard"
    size="small"
    type="number"
    inputProps={{
      min: '0',
      oninput: "validity.valid||(value='');",
    }}
    onChange="validity.valid||(value='');"
  />
```

As the MUI [doc](https://mui.com/api/input/) says,

> inputProps    object      {}    [Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes) applied to the input element.

And well, `oninput` is a valid Event attribute for the `input` element but on render, the underlying native HTML input element has only the `min` attribute defined and the `oninput` attribute is missing.

What is going wrong here? I even tried it with onChange but to no success.

Comment: try with camel case `onInput` [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58558085/why-events-in-react-have-uppercase-letter-in-the-second-key-word)

Comment: @diedu oh yeah forgot to add it, I have tried but it doesnt work

Comment: says `onInput` should be a function not a string. for example  `onInput: (e) => console.log(e.target.value)`  should print the value of input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass a function parameter as `onInput` prop instead of a string like this:

```
const handleOnInput = (e) => {
    //e.target.value
};

<Input
    value={val}
    variant="standard"
    size="small"
    type="number"
    inputProps={{
      min: "0",
      onInput: handleOnInput
    }}
/>
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-mountain-3n4x4) for live working example.